# System.Windows.Control.Image does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm new to C# and WP8 Programming, I'm creating an app in which I've created a button click event which will change the source of "Main_Frame" image when clicked-

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    Main_Frame.Source = new Image(new Uri("/Assets/BG2.jpg", UriKind.Relative));              
}
```

Why am i getting this error `"System.Windows.Control.Image does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"` ?

Any help?

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory to me. I suspect you want `BitmapImage` instead of `Image`, setting the `UriSource` property.

Comment: This sure helped me, but whenever i click on the next button the image goes blank. What am i doing wrong? Is there other easy way of doing it? :/

Comment: Well we don't know what your new code looks like, which makes it hard to help you.